# How to insert and then update returned Id from insert query as returning id in a single command in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have a demo table

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id SERIAL primary key,
  user_id integer,
  name character varying,
  created timestamp with time zone default now()
);
```

And I want a single query to run and first insert data, then return primary key using returning id and then update the same table with the returned id.

```
INSERT INTO items (name) values ('pen') RETURNING id as idd 
update items set user_id=(select idd) where id=(select idd)
```

but the above command doesn't work and throws syntax error.
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Why would you like to change the primary key?

Comment: I am not changing the primary key, I just want to insert primary key that I got in user_id column.

Comment: What about adding a trigger to `items` table that sets column `user_id` to the generated `id` value, instead of performing an UPDATE immediately after an INSERT? In any case, why do you store the ID twice in the same table? Doesn't that contradict [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: Have a particular requirement as this will not be true in every case. I am creating some sort of tree structure in database. Discussed about the trigger with my senior but they said it will unnecessarily complex the table and database structure

Comment: If the database trigger is not an option, what about a PL/pgSQL routine that performs both the INSERT and the subsequent UPDATE? Or does that also make the structure unnecessarily complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that right within the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO items 
  (name, user_id) 
values 
  ('pen', currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('items','id')));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=187cde020d8f493ff1e39f7a11784ea8)

Comment: Thanks it worked. So instead of currval can returning Id be used if so how :)

Comment: @SanyamMadaan: no, you can not refer to other columns in the `values` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also :

```
create temp table insert_item as 
with insert_item_cte as ( 
INSERT INTO items (name) 
 values ('pen') returning id 
) 
select id from insert_item_cte;

update items set user_id = items.id 
from insert_item ii 
where ii.id = items.id;
```

[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7549023ec689212c941e381aaa188d58)